# Missing data Prediction

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, prediction

I have jester data; the data has 100 movies, and their rating is given by 24983 users, and the data has lots of missing data. My job is predicting it.

I want to start with the Decision Tree,

I'm thinking that First, I will select the first column of data (it has the first movie ratings), and then I will delete the first column from the data. Then, I will fit them, and finally, I will find the prediction probability of the first column (which is deleted from the data)

I'm working on Python

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

df = pd.read_excel(input_file, header=None)
matrix = df.as_matrix()

imp = Imputer(missing_values=99, strategy='mean', axis=0)
imp.fit(matrix)
matrix= imp.transform(matrix)

train_data = matrix[:,:90] #train data (train data has 90 column)
test_data = matrix[:,90:]  #%10 test data (test data has 10 column)

array2 = train_data.copy()
column = array2[:,0]                # 0. column should be delete
array2 = np.delete(array2,0,axis=1) # 0. column should be select

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=25) 
clf.fit(array2.astype(int), column.astype(int))
clf_probs = clf.predict_proba(column)
```

My last giving error

> `ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 89 and input n_features is 24983`

I have to predict the column like what I tell you (above the code)

What should I do? I really need help.

Comment: Grab some tutorials first. One about recommender-systems and one about sklearn. The former will show you, that classic supervised algorithms like DecisionTree's alone are not widely used for that (theory problems; check out matrix-factorization which is simple and working great). The latter will show you how to prepare the data within sklearn (practice).

Comment: Thanks for advice but, I'm working on it 3 weeks and there is a fail like it. Could you tell me more in detail?

Comment: Well... i just told you that the approach is probably doomed (theoretic-wise) and the data-processing pipeline is basic. Not sure if you should continue hacking on this blindly to be honest.

Comment: @FurkanYıldız: I concur with sascha.  (1) The approach you've chosen is more superstition -- data science strongly suggests that it won't give you an effective path to a good solution.  The experiment you're doing is one of the ways Data Science discovered it's generally a bad idea.  (2) Your code is failing because you fed the data observations as if they're features -- you turned your table sideways.  (3) In both of these, you need to research the paradigm you're using.  Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site; those open, "tell me more in detail" questions are well outside what we do here.